# Draggable Arrow with UIView

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios, draggable, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to create an draggable Arrow which can be moved in any direction on both sides(as in the picture)

[image]

Is there a possibility to do something?

I've tried something like this:

[image]

Its an UIView with two Subviews(Blue and Green).

Answer (score 0):

You could add the gesture recognizer to the containing view, and then based on the event, you alter your views.